In Video.js, Video is starting playing from beginning when the progress bar is clicked
After the browser is launched, select a video through the button and add it to video.js. The video can be played normally. But when dragging the progress bar, it always starts playing from beginning when released.
The Steps to reproduce is:

Click the button to selected a video;
The Video.js play the video normally;
Dragging the progress bar;
The video start playing from beginning.

The version of videojs is 8.18.1, the browser is Edge, the OS is Windows 11. The Video.js is used in Element plus (VUE3), and the code is as follows:
<template>
    <el-container style="">
        <el-main>
            <el-container >
                <el-card >
                    <el-row>
                        <video
                            ref="videoPlayer"
                            class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                            controls
                            preload="auto"
                            style="width: 100%;height: 500px;"
                            >
                        </video>
                    </el-row>
                </el-card>
            </el-container>
        </el-main>
    </el-container>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import { Delete, Aim } from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
import { genFileId, ElMessage, ElMessageBox } from 'element-plus'
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css'

const videoPlayer = ref()
let selectedVideoPlayer = null


//init the videojs 
onMounted(() => {
    selectedVideoPlayer = videojs(videoPlayer.value, {
        controls: true,
        sources: [],
    });
})

// add a new video to videjs through url
const handleAddToDisplay = (index, row) => {
    console.log(index, row)

    let selectedVideoUrl = "http://xxx.mp4"
    console.log(selectedVideoUrl)
    changeDisplayedVideoSource(selectedVideoUrl)
    selectedVideoFile.value.videoFileName = row.videoFileName
    selectedVideoFile.value.videoFrameRate = row.videoFrameRate
}

// change the video source
const changeDisplayedVideoSource = (newSrc) => {
    selectedVideoPlayer.src([
        {
            src: newSrc,
            type: 'video/mp4'
        }
    ]);

    selectedVideoPlayer.ready(() => {
        const videoInfo = selectedVideoPlayer.currentHeight() + 'x' + selectedVideoPlayer.currentWidth()
        console.log(videoInfo)
    })

    selectedVideoPlayer.load()
    selectedVideoPlayer.play()
};
</script>


You'll need to provide a runnable example that can be debugged.  Even with the code shown, the issue is not reproducible.  Video.js by default allows the dragging of the progressbar and playing different parts of the video, so whatever the bug is must be unique to your application.

This symptom is always because the server doesn't respond correctly to Content-Range headers. When you seek, the browser will request a range of bytes. If the server responds with the start of the file instead of that range, that is what is played. There's nothing you can adjust client-side, it must be fixed server-side.

My first thought too.
